# Custom git push command in RStudio

Tags: r, git

I tried poking around the resources for RStudio but to no avail. I want to substitute the script behind the green push button inside RStudio with a custom bash script. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could pre-commit hooks help?

Comment: @phd possibly. Know of a way to work one in with the Rstudio commit GUI?

Comment: I don't know Rstudio but I believe it doesn't commit itself — it calls `git` so hooks must work.

Comment: @phd right. The challenge is finding where the hooks are.

Comment: If Rstudio uses git — there have to be a directory named `.git/`. Look for subdirectory `.git/hooks/`